# Having trouble adding font to Android App

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to add a font to my android app using the following code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/digi.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewA);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

I get the error: cannot find symbol: class Typeface and  cannot find symbol: variable Typeface

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: this is case sensitive make sure its spelled correctly. where have you put the font file what path?

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: Thanks for your responses. How would I go about cleaning the project?

Comment: Eclipse Toolbar Project->Clean

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should make sure you have resources.  When I get anything from assets or resources, I preface it a context  like this:

```
someTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "sometypeface.otf");
someString = getResources().getString(R.string.somestring);
```

without a context, your code may not be have access to fonts

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Should I be changing mContext?

Comment: you're not using a context at all in your code.  In my example, mContext is something I passed in to a method and is simply a Context. The second example using getResources() is also useful in getting strings, images, etc out of resources. WIthout using that, you can get some strange image artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses, I finally figured out the issue. I was creating a new textview when I wanted to edit an existing one. Appreciate the help.